# Why did Gerty sudenly reveal the secret of the Lunar Industries to Sam?

Tags: moon

The two Sams got in to an argument about which one is a clone and which is not:

```
SAM2:  You're a fucking clone.
       You don't have shit.

SAM1:  Hey, I'm going home.

SAM2:  You're not going anywhere.
       You know, you've been up here too long, man.
       You've lost your marbles.
       What, do you think Tess is back home,
       waiting for you on the sofa in lingerie?
       What about the original Sam? Huh?

SAM1:  I'm the original Sam!
       I'm Sam fucking Bell!
       Gerty, am I a clone?

GERTY: Are you hungry?
```

Gerty would not answer the question.

Later Sam 1. has asked about his video messages that he sent to his wife while network communication was down:

```
SAM:   Gerty...
       Am I really a clone?

GERTY: When you first arrived at Sarang, there was a small crash.
       You woke up in the Infirmary.
       You suffered minor brain damage and memory loss.
       I kept you under observation and ran some tests.

SAM:   I remember, yeah. I remember that.

GERTY: Sam, there was no crash.
       You were being awakened.
       It is standard procedure for all new clones to be given tests
       to establish mental stability and general physical health.
```

Why did Gerty suddenly reveal the secret that he was supposed to keep. In all other parts of the movie, he followed his programming - helped Sam in any way he could while keeping the secret for himself. Why did he suddenly change?

Comment: He possibly had a change of heart, because the computer was more "human" than those who devised that clone worker program.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Well the premise of my question was that he actually was more computer-like, than most robots in most movies. This was essentially his only mistake. Except for this moment, he always followed his programming: "Protect Sam"

Comment: I seems to me that one of points of movie was that his looks were misleading. There's no reason to think he was more "programmed" then anyone. Especially Sam was kinda programmed, and was expendable, while Gerty wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

I always felt like at that point, Gerty probably was either programmed or felt that Sam was going to die in the next few hours/days anyway, so there's not too much reason to keep it from him any longer. He probably couldn't do too much damage to the base in his weakened condition, and it didn't seem plausible that he could escape. Plus, even if he did, he's going to die in a matter of hours or days, so it hardly matters.